# Can you pass a _tag as a rails helper argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two form field types (`f.text_field` or `f.text_area`) that I want to define through a helper:

```
def helper_thing(tagtype, field_id)
  tagtype("#{field_id}", class: 'input-group-field')
end
```

I want to use `tagtype` as a variable for either form text helper in the view (using haml):

```
= helper_thing(f.text_field, 'random_id')
```

I'm hoping the output would be something like:

```
f.text_field('random_id')
```

I always get an error saying "invalid number of args 0 of 1..3)" essentially causing the rest of my arguments to fail. For the sake of brevity I only used one argument in my example though.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible:

```
def helper_thing(form, tagtype, field_id)
  form.send(tagtype, "#{field_id}", class: 'input-group-field')
end
```

Call:

```
= helper_thing(f, :text_field, 'random_id')
```

The problem with your attempt was that you tried to pass in `f.text_field`, which is a call of the `text_field` method on `f` without arguments. Since said method expects 1-3 arguments you end up with the error you saw.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Michael Kohls excellent answer there is one additional way of doing this without changing the method signature.

Since parens are optional in Ruby all objects have a special `method` method which can be used if you want a reference to a method - without calling it:

```
= helper_thing(f.method(:text_field), 'random_id')
```

Then use `.call` on the passed Method object:

```
def helper_thing(tagtype, field_id)
  tagtype.call("#{field_id}", class: 'input-group-field')
end
```

Comment: You might want to look into creating a custom form builder instead of using a helper though. It lets you add methods to the `f` object instead of passing around a bunch of references. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html